# Am I legally allowed to use logos that I create using online logo making software for clients?

Tags: copyright

I often do freelance app and web development and design. Sometimes I have clients ask if I do logos as well, I don't personally know a lot about graphic design but am familiar with some online software for logo making (particularly canva). So am I allowed to use these logos I make through canva and other software in the apps or sites that I make for clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say Canva gives you "exactly the same rights as Microsoft Word" but in most cases you do retain full ownership of anything you publish on Canva.  An example of an exception is if you use Stock images (that are owned by someone else) in your work, you obviously don't automatically own those images.  Or, if your employer paid you specifically to create the item, then you might not hold all rights.

The site has a number of extremely detailed pages outlining the terms and conditions such as [this](https://about.canva.com/terms-of-use/) one, but they were kind enough to include a "plain language" column on the right side of the page.

A quote from the **Contributor Agreement**:

> 2.1 **Ownership**. Nothing contained in this Agreement shall be construed to transfer any copyrights to Canva. The copyrights in and to all
>   Stock Media remains with the owner of such copyrights. Any and all
>   Stock Media submitted to the Service must be your own original work.

If you're unsure about your individual situation, it's best to confirm directly with the company; they even have [an online form](https://support.canva.com/legal/forms/legal-form/) *just* for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in exactly the same way you are allowed to use novels you write in Microsoft Word.